# What happens if we don't check "Completed" status (Paypal IPN)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Here is a part of my Paypal IPN code :

```
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
{
     /* something here */
}
```

What could happen if I **don't** check if `paypal_status` is `Completed` ?

I have never seen a payment yet with `paypal_status` different of `Completed`... What are the other possibilities ?

Answer (score 1):

There's several edge cases to test for

1. Reversed - Caused by a chargeback
2. Canceled_Reversal - You won a chargeback dispute
3. Pending - Most often caused by someone using a Paypal account to pay without a backup funding source. Can sometimes happen to credit card payments too but considerably more rare.
4. Voided - You voided an authorization
5. Expired - an authorization expired

A more complete list can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB04C0HS)

Comment: Thank you very much.
So what should I add in my code ? Do you think 
`if (strcmp ($paypal_status, "Completed") == 0)`  will work ?

Comment: Just do `if($paypal_status == 'Completed')` and then `elseif`, etc